# Dynamoose query by different attributes (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, dynamoose

I need to get record (-s) from `DynamoDB` via `Dynamoose` by non-key attribute. For example, I need to get all records from the table `someModel` where the field `my_field` is equal to `111`. I do it by the next way:

```
const data = await someModel.query("my_field").eq("111").exec();
```

And this code stops executing! I mean that following code after that is not called.

If I change code to this:

```
const data = await someModel.query("my_field").eq("111");
```

my query is working, but `data` contains:

```
{
  "options": {
    "all": {
      "delay": 0,
      "max": 1
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "hashKey": {
      "name": "my_field",
      "value": "111"
    }
  },
  "filters": {},
  "buildState": false,
  "validationError": null,
  "notState": false,
  "success": true
}
```

I understand that above code is prepared query parameters for query but how can I apply them and execute query to `DynamoDB`? Of course the query code is placing inside `async` function - that is why `await` is written there.

I use also `serverless` framework for describing `DynamoDB` schemes. But all models I write via `dynamoose`.

Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#query), Dynamoose `query` returns the value in the callback and not as a promise. Therefore, your response is actually returned in a callback that should come inside the `exec` part of your query. `async/await` is valid for promises and not callbacks.

```
someModel.query("my_field").eq("111").exec((err, data) => {
    // Do whatever you wish to with your data
});
```

Comment: Hi, @nerdier.js! I saw that docs and I tried to do by this way but got next error: "ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id"

Comment: @vitaliy It could be that you aren't including the primary key while running a query over the Dynamodb table. Are you sure my_field is the primary key of the table ?

Comment: Of course `my_field` is non primary key field :) But!!! this field has described as Global Secondary Index, so I expected that `query` method will work. At this moment I solved my issue with `scan` method but I want to understand how can I use `query` method.

Comment: To use the query method with Dynamodb, remember that query can only be used with primary keys - at the moment, it is a limitation of th dynamodb. You may also wish to explore the options of creating global and local secondary indexes if in case you don't wish to turn my_field into a primary key. The methods of retrieval would be slightly different.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. Could you provide some example or links where I can read about including another field to primary (maybe is it `RANGE` key schema?) and about methods for those purposes? Would be very grateful!

Comment: @vitaliy Are you wanting to query based on another property? If so you can do something like the `breed` property as seen [here](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#schema). Basically you just use an `index` [property](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#attribute-definitions) in your attribute definition.